# Журнал событий через .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, php, вирусы

Как в .htaccess добавить php скрипт, который бы при обращении к любому php|html, кроме index.php файлу незаметно выполнял какие-нибудь действие. Например, ввел журнал, сколько раз открывался тот или иной файл (просто интересует, что нужно добавить в .htaccess, а php скрипт сам допишу).

Цель такая, есть сайт в нем куча php или html файлов, все они подгружаются инклудом в index.php. А иногда на сайте появляются левые файлы, например, system.php, который является вирусным и время от времени с определенного IP адреса запускают этот скрипт и начинается заражение всех файлов. Хотелось бы найти все php файлы, которые запуcкаются не через index.php, а на прямую.

Блокировка ip адреса, проверка юзер агента и откуда он пришел, проверка компов, смена паролей на фтп, сайты, чистка вируса и многое другое уже наделал, больше сил нету :((

Comment: а если в index.php объвить некоторую константу, а во всех остальных файлах проверять ее наличие, при этом в .htaccess перенаправлять все на index.php?

Comment: а также поискать дыры в коде? Хотя предложение Dex очень уместно - это будет первая линия обороны.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, буду смотреть в эту сторону если ничего не найду.
но все же, решение не очень мне подходит, т.к. на сайте есть файлы, которые должны самостоятельно запускатся, что касается переменых там есть и идет проверка, я просто хочу найти те файлы, которые идут уже не с самой КМС, а были добавлены после, с вирусами. На площадке у меня сайты с джумлой, ModX, DLE и на студийной КМС.

Answer (score 3):

`php_value auto_prepend_file check.php`
В нем уже проверка на файл index.php в запросе.